# discord.js check event channel has permission or not

Tags: node.js, events, discord.js

how can i check the channel permissions to send message

In my case i am in an event called userUpdate.js where my code is something like

```
module.exports =  async (client,oldUser, newUser) => {

    if (newUser.bot) return;    
    if(oldUser.username === newUser.username) return ;

        var log = client.guilds.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('member-log'));
        if (log != null) 
        var sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
           .setColor("RANDOM")
           .setTimestamp()
           .setDescription(`**OLD-USER** <@${oldUser.username}> **NEW-USER**\n<@${newUser.id}>`)
        log.send(sEmbed);
}
```

but it doesn't have message parameter like in message event so how can i check bots permission

```
if (!message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;
```

so how shall i put this in the userUpdate.js event file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have the variable `log` which is the channel you want to send the message to.
Just use the same snippet as above, but replace `message.channel` with `log`.

```
if (!log.permissionsFor(client.user).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;
```

Also: Your error handling is pretty bad in the script above and may could make more errors instead of preventing them.
Probably try just returning if log is null. You could replace the line `if (log != null)` with `if (!log) return;`

Comment: yah i changed that `!log`  just after putting question here

Comment: Oh okay. Did the permission check work? Also, if you want to check for permissions before sending an embed, you may also want to check for `EMBED_LINKS` which is also required to send embeds.

Comment: yah i will add that too